# Android Things for RaspBerry

Tags: android-things

I have a problem to install the image of Android on MicroSD for my RaspBerry Pi3 Model B+.
I have followed all the steps indicated on the link "https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi".
When the application, I use the Windows, "android-things-setup-utility-windows.exe" returns ok I put the MicroSD inside my Raspberry and I obtain a multicolor stripe.
Which is the problem? Maybe this image is for Raspberry Pi3 Model B whereas mine is RaspBerry Pi3 Model B+?
Help me please, I ask here because on the internet there is only the unofficial version Android.
Best Regards,
Fiore

Comment: go to https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi ... use the search button at top of page to find `raspbery pi 3b` ... the FAQ tells you that RPi 3B+ and RPi 4 are not supported at this time

Comment: Please, see [Does Android Things support the Raspberry Pi 3 model B+?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49434627/3290339)